# How to detect opened application with Ruby

Tags: ruby, outlook, shellexecute

I'm making my first application using Ruby.
The thing is that I open outlook using shell.ShellExecute('outlook.exe',...
But I need to know if outllok is already open or not. (the script make an outlook instance everytime I call it... it's bad for me :p !)

Second question. When I open an application with shellExecute, is it possible to minimise it after opening ?

Thx !

Comment: Anyway good question,I learned lot's today from this question. *+1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***All can be done using Ruby Standard library*** [`win32ole`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html).

---

> ***Second question. When I open an application with shellExecute, is it possible to minimise it after opening ?***

Yes there is an option in doing so(taken from [`rubyonwindows`](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/launching-apps-and-printing-docs-with.html)):

```
shell.ShellExecute(FILE, ARGUMENTS, DIRECTORY, OPERATION, SHOW)
```

Now Look below:

> SHOW: Recommends how the window that belongs to the application that performs the operation should be displayed initially (0 = hidden, 1 = normal, ***2 = minimized***, 3 = maximized). The application can ignore this recommendation. If this parameter is not specified, the application uses its default value.

---

> ***But I need to know if outlook is already open or not.***

Yes there is an option in doing so(taken from [`Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)`](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/search/label/wmi))

```
require 'win32ole'

shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')

wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
processes = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process")
processes.each{|i| p "already opened" if i.name == "OUTLOOK.EXE"}
# => nil
shell.ShellExecute('OUTLOOK.EXE')

wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
processes = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process")
processes.each{|i| p "already opened" if i.name == "OUTLOOK.EXE"}
# => "already opened"
```

Comment: @user1838902 Glad to hear that I at-least helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether Outlook is running, first install sys-proctable:

```
gem install sys-proctable
```

Then you can do this:

```
require 'sys/proctable'

puts Sys::ProcTable.ps.select{ |pe| pe.caption == "OUTLOOK.EXE" }.any?
```

Which returns true if there is a process with the name "OUTLOOK.EXE". This should be sufficient.